# How to reset AICC/Scorm course progress when re assigning a course to the student

Tags: scorm, scorm1.2, lms

I want to reset the student previous completed course progress, I am assigning the same course to student again but it is showing the course as already completed.

While re-assigning the course I am setting the location data as 0 or blank but it's taking the location data from LRS and marking the course as completed, course not using my location data that I am giving over AICC get param call.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what LMS you are using and which standard you're using, the answer to this could be any of the following:

1. It can't be reset, the values are locked in after the first completion is achieved;
2. It can only be reset by an administrative action in the LMS, not from within the course launch itself;
3. Some values can be overwritten but not others;
4. Values can be overwritten through the appropriate API.

Outside of that, since it's a "re-assignment", that's not a feature of either AICC or SCORM, that's always implemented at the LMS level, and it will be specific to your LMS vendor as to what that word means and how they implement the data storage.

SCORM and AICC work completely differently in these contexts as well, so you'll want to be more specific about:
A) Which LMS you're trying to do this on;
B) Which exact standard you're using (SCORM 1.2, SCORM 2004, AICC, xAPI, cmi5, etc.)

This is probably a question best sent to your LMS vendor, they're likely to be the ones who can address what the rules around re-assignment are on their own platform.

Comment: Thank you, I am itself a LMS developer, the issue is with AICC and Scorm 1.2 both but AICC is important for now. I am deleting all the previous progress (lesson_location) of the user and sending it in AICC getparam.

Answer (score 0):

You're sending mixed messages with your question: an LRS is for xAPI courses, not SCORM courses, and a SCORM course does not use AICC calls.

Assuming you're using SCORM for the course and a standard LMS:

Ensure the course's exit mode is set to `normal` when setting a completion (and be sure to commit). If the exit mode is set to `suspend`, the course will  open with the same SCORM session (same 'attempt').

I think of it as:

- Exit mode `suspend` = allow learners to relaunch the course with existing data. The learner can review their progress without altering their existing completion status or score (assuming course is constructed in a way that facilitates post-completion reviews).
- Exit mode `normal` = the next time the learner launches the course, it will start a brand new attempt.

If you're already doing these things and the course continues to launch with the old data, you need to check with your LMS provider.